# How to reduce duplication of similar build configurations?

Tags: teamcity

I have several projects that I'd like to have in separate build configurations with *slightly* different configurations:

- VCS source and build triggers (i.e. the only difference is which subdirectory of the projects root dir to use)
- build steps (the first few are the exact same, but the last few may vary depending on how the unit tests are to be run, dependencies, etc.)

That's it.  I looked into Build Configuration Templates, but it seems that does not allow the flexibility of specifying custom build steps **or** extra VCS roots.

Really I'm just looking to not have to manually copy the (several) build steps from our initial project's build configuration into several more configurations, and to have to maintain them all when things change.  It seems there should be a better solution?

Comment: Which TeamCity version are you using? [Build Configuration Template](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Configuration+Template) works for me.

Comment: @user1177636 Yeah, I think it will end up working for my case as well.  I will just need to mess around with the parameters a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I've wondered this as well, but the bits I've found online suggest you favor the redundancy instead of trying to reuse one configuration across your multiple branches or projects.

However, all of that was before version 8 was released, which introduces the ability to extract a [meta-runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Meta-Runner)

Their blog [from April 13, 2013](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/04/) provides a good summary of what they are and how they differ from templates.

> Meta-runner
>
> Meta Runner is a powerful feature providing a promising new way for customizing TeamCity and making it even more people-oriented. To understand it, let’s consider an example.
>
> Imagine you have some repeated task used over and over again across different build configurations. The task is defined as one or more build steps, based on built-in runners, like Ant or command line. Most likely you’d want to reuse this task easily across several build configurations. You can’t do this with templates because template enforces you to share the same settings across different configurations which is not always possible. A solution which we propose is to extract Meta-runner out of these steps, see how it works in release notes.

I have yet to implement this, but I will be testing it out soon. It makes me think that you should be able to pass the repository in as a parameter, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to get it working with a template after a little hackery with the build parameters, but if I find it more trouble than it's worth this will be a good alternative to try.

Comment: Some examples of meta-runners are available on GitHub: https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack

Comment: @jwalk yah I had heard the same thing, you make it more complex by hacking on it to be reusable. Also, are you using build chains? You can have build + unit test => installer => auto integration => deploy to QA. Many of those chains can be extracted as a template and used as is, pretty easily.

Comment: @jwalk I just saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625547/teamcity-artifact-from-lastsuccessful-branch-build  I haven't tried it yet but it sounds promising.

Comment: I know this question is old, but the problem with meta-runners is they don't  share parameters; the parameters in a meta-runner appear to be "sand-boxed" to themselves. In my experience, this greatly reduces their usefulness. For example, I want a parameter named `%version%` that spans several meta-runners that all use the same version. As of TeamCity 10, I have to redefine all the parameters in each meta-runner.

Comment: @NathanAidenSr I gave up on TeamCity and switched to Jenkins a couple years ago. The big reason was the duplication, and I didn't like the chaining of builds. I think TeamCity is a bit more straight-forward than Jenkins but I like the control and possibilities in Jenkins. YMMV, I just can't provide an updated approach on TC.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while and developed a tool to manage it, I call it [Dictator Builder](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-builder).

For a long time, we have been working with "template"-projects. Basically it is a repository that has a fully working application complete with all build configurations needed. Much like [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) is. We have several template projects, one for each type of application we develop.

Problem with this is keeping copied code in synk with the template project.

I now have the template code packaged within a "dictator". Like this:
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-react-boilerplate/tree/master/dictatables/static-files/react-boilerplate

The dictator dictates that some static files should be copied to the root of a dictated folder.

```
{
  "message": "Copy react-boilerplate",
  "actions": [
    {
      "copyFrom": "react-boilerplate",
      "target": "."
    }
  ]
}
```

The dictator can be run from command line like `npx dictator-react-boilerplate@version`. It will dictate the current working directory, typically your code base in an application. It can be configured by the code base in a [.dictatorconfig.json](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-react-boilerplate-example/blob/master/.dictatorconfig.json) file. Perhaps choose not to be dictated on some parts:

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "/app",
    "/package.json",
    "/package-lock.json",
    "/Changelod.md"
  ]
}
```

So that most of the build configuration from the template is just copied to the dictated code base. And the `app` folder, and other things, are still managed by the code base.

When cloned, the folder looks like:

```
app
coverage
.dictatorconfig.json
docs
.gitignore
internals
LICENSE.md
node_modules
package.json
README.md
server
```

And after `npm install`, or after `npx dictator-react-boilerplate@version` it looks like:

```
.all-contributorsrc
app
appveyor.yml
babel.config.js
Changelog.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
coverage
.dictatorconfig.json
docs
.editorconfig
.eslintrc.js
.gitattributes
.gitignore
internals
jest.config.js
LICENSE.md
node_modules
.nvmrc
package.json
package-lock.json
.prettierignore
.prettierrc
README.md
server
.stylelintrc
.travis.yml
```